# write a regular expression to extract a word that follows a pattern

Tags: python, sql, pandas, regex

I have a column that has data as below. From this I need to extract the 1 word that comes after approved by,Approver is, Approval from etc. The first 1 word/name that comes after keyword "approv". approv should be case insensitive.

Ex -

row 1- incident 12345, issue is so and so, solution is so and so.Ticket was approved by **thors**

row 2-incident 12900, issue is so and so, solution is so and so. approver is : **Wanda** Advocate worked julie

row 3-incident 125790, issue is so and so, solution is so and so. Ticket was got approval from- **spiderman**, closing

row 4-incident 125790, issue is so and so, solution is so and so. Ticket was approved by- **ironman**, blah blah

I tried to do \bApprov*\b([\w][A-Za-z]{4-7}) - but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a solution quite similar to yours, I hope it works for you. At least for this particular case it returns the output you needed:

```py
import regex as re

string = """row 1- incident 12345, issue is so and so, solution is so and so.Ticket was approved by thors

row 2-incident 12900, issue is so and so, solution is so and so. approver is : Wanda Advocate worked julie

row 3-incident 125790, issue is so and so, solution is so and so. Ticket was got approval from- spiderman, closing

row 4-incident 125790, issue is so and so, solution is so and so. Ticket was approved by- ironman, blah blah"""

for row in string.split("\n"):
    if row.startswith("row"):
        m = re.search(r"(?i)(?<=approv[A-Z\s\-\:]+)[A-Z]{5,}", row)
        print(m.group(0))
```

Output:

```bash
thors
Wanda
spiderman
ironman
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve this using python? If so the code below may be helpfull.

code:

```
    rows = ['incident 12345, issue is so and so, solution is so and so.Ticket was approved by Thors'
            , 'incident 12900, issue is so and so, solution is so and so. approver is : Wanda Advocate worked julie'
            , 'incident 125790, issue is so and so, solution is so and so. Ticket was got approval from- spiderman, closing'
            , 'incident 125790, issue is so and so, solution is so and so. Ticket was approved by- ironman, blah blah']

    for row in rows:
        clean_row = row.translate({ord(x): None for x in ',.;:[]()-'})
        split_row = clean_row.lower().split('approv')[-1].split()[2]
        print(split_row)
```

output:

```
    thors
    wanda
    spiderman
    ironman
```

Answer (score 0):

using this callback function resolves the issue.

`txt.replace(/(?<=[a-z0-9]+)\s+[\:\-]/gi, x => x.trim()).match(/(?<=(approv)[a-z]+\s)[a-z\s\-\:]+/gi).join().split(' ')[1]`

explanation:

1. I am using `txt.replace(/(?<=[a-z0-9]+)\s+[\:\-]/gi, x => x.trim())`, because there is some input issue at 2nd input string: `row 2-incident 12900, issue is so and so, solution is so and so. approver is : Wanda Advocate worked julie`. Add extra space between 'approver is' and ':'
2. regex: `txt.match(/(?<=(approv)[a-z]+\s)[a-z\s\-\:]+/gi).join().split(' ')[1]`. Then find the remaining words after 'approv*' keyword and print 2nd word.

code:

```
var ar = [`row 1- incident 12345, issue is so and so, solution is so and so.Ticket was approved by thors`,
`row 2-incident 12900, issue is so and so, solution is so and so. approver is : Wanda Advocate worked julie`,
`row 3-incident 125790, issue is so and so, solution is so and so. Ticket was got approval from- spiderman, closing`,
`row 4-incident 125790, issue is so and so, solution is so and so. Ticket was approved by- ironman, blah blah`]

ar.forEach(txt => {
  console.log(txt.replace(/(?<=[a-z0-9]+)\s+[\:\-]/gi, x => x.trim()).match(/(?<=(approv)[a-z]+\s)[a-z\s\-\:]+/gi).join().split(' ')[1]);
})
```

Output:

```
thors
Wanda
spiderman
ironman
```